# Balloon amounts in Bloon TD 5?

Tags: bloons-td-5

How much is each different balloon worth when popped and what types of balloons are there? It seems that the moabs give less cash than the actual red balloons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that all balloons are worth 1 when popped - MOABs simply give more cash because they contain a lot of balloons.

Here's a balloon type list: http://bloons-tower-defense-5.blogspot.com/p/bloon-types.html

Comment: I think at later stages you get a lot less per balloon, or else I should be earning tens of thousands per round when there are hundreds of ZOMGs but I don't see that much money.

Comment: That is true: after round 50, I believe, balloons drop much less money.

Comment: 1 layer of bloons is basically equivalent to $1 in game

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you destroy MOABs, It gives you no money. For example a ZOMG, the BFBs   inside it, and the MOABs inside it don't give money. but the ceramics will. Only actual BALLOONS give you money.